# Can I run mayactl from my nodes (OpenEBS)?

Tags: openebs

I don't have access to the namespace openebs and maya-apiserver. Can I run mayactl on my nodes to get the same information? If yes, how does mayactl know which PVCs/PVs I have access to? How does it protect other volumes from accidental deletion via mayactl volume delete?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from maya-apiserver pod. You can do it with the below command in the master node. 
`kubectl exec -it <pod name> -n openebs bash`

Once you are inside the pod, you can run required mayactl command

Else you can run the command directly as per below format.

`kubectl exec -it <pod name> -n openebs <required mayactl command>`